# How to crop an image by extreme points? OPENCV - PYTHON

Tags: python, image, opencv

I have a image like this: 
[image]

I want to crop it like this:
[image]

I just need four points, upper right, upper left etc. It needs to be optimized and fast, python 3 opencv.

Comment: Have you implemented anything that you found to be too slow?

Comment: Yes, four looping, to find each point. It wasn't too slow, but it wasn't fast.

Comment: Can you paste some of that code into your post?

Comment: Sum all the rows across the image and find first and last row that don't sum to zero. Sum all the columns down the image and find the first and last columns that don't sum to zero. For added fun, do the two in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do contour detection to detect the bounding box then extract the ROI

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

for c in cnts:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = original[y:y+h, x:x+w].copy()
    cv2.rectangle(original, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (36,255,12), 2)

cv2.imshow('ROI', ROI)
cv2.imwrite('ROI.png', ROI)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it when I get home!

Comment: It worked fine, see what you think about my solution.

Comment: Your method works as well but it has a lot of case checking. Both work :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an efficient way, very fast. Thanks to Mark Setchell and Nathancy.

```
colsums = np.sum(img, axis=0)
linessum = np.sum(img, axis=1)
colsums2 = np.nonzero(0-colsums)                                                                 
linessum2 = np.nonzero(0-linessum)    

xx=linessum2[0][0]                                                               
yy=linessum2[0][linessum2[0].shape[0]-1]    
ww=colsums2[0][0]
hh=colsums2[0][colsums2[0].shape[0]-1]
if xx > 4 :
    xx = xx-5
else :
    xx = 0 

if ww > 4 :
    ww = ww-5
else :
    ww = 0

if hh < img.shape[1] -6:
    hh=hh+5
else :
    hh=img.shape[1]-1

if yy < img.shape[0] -6:
    yy=yy+5
else :
    yy=img.shape[0]-1  

imgcrop = img[xx:yy, ww:hh]
```